# Multiple Phone number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate multiple phone numbers comma separated using regular expression in javascript.

For single number my regex is `/03[0-9]{9}$/`

i need to test this : 03123465789,03335678990,03453465789

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would use `.split(',')` and check validation in each loop

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check if a string ends with a series of phone numbers of a given pattern separated by comma, try this:

```
(?:03[0-9]{9}(?:,|$))+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dE1wD2/1

**Explanation:**

The `(?:,|$)` ensures a phone number of your desired pattern either ends with comma or appears to be the last number in the string. The final "$" is put to ensure no other stuff comes after the numbers.

**Update:**

Just to be more precise and exclude lists ending with a comma, append a look-ahead "not an end of line" condition to the comma (i.e. `,(?!$)`):

```
(?:03[0-9]{9}(?:,(?!$)|$))+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dE1wD2/2